# Unicode characters in XeLatex

Tags: latex, fonts, tex, xelatex

This is my LaTex script:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Jenson Classico}
\begin{document}
ąęśćłó
\end{document}
```

I compile this using xelatex through eclipse plugin.

As Jenson Classico has no polish characters I have edited this font to add them. In Microsoft Office it works fine (I am able to use polish characters). Unfortunately in pdf generated from above tex-file it doesn't. If I use any other font (e.g. Arial) it works like a dream.

Any suggesions? I really don't have any more ideas...

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `polyglossia` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setdefaultlanguage{polish}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Jenson Classico}
\begin{document}
ąęśćłó
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is that font Jenson Classico a unicode font ? Trying using other Polish unicode font. If nothing works, post the question in http://tex.stackexchange.com/ there are some good peoples there.

Answer (score -2):

Use `\char"` followed by the Unicode value.

For example, ąęśćłó would be: `\char"0105\char"0119\char"015B\char"0107\char"0142\char"00F3`.

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me.


\documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  \char"0105\char"0119\char"015B\char"0107\char"0142\char"00F3
  \end{document}